# Effects of accidentally transferring pockets of air into body

Tags: science-based, medicine

An innovative treatment for cancer and broken bones involves the precise removal and replacement of the affected tissue with artificially grown tissue. The tissue (or piece of bone) is "beamed" in and out by the Handwavac-70 machine. Rarely, due to handling errors - somewhat similar to the Therac-25 failures-, the new tissue is discarded instead and an equivalent volume of ambient air transferred into the original tumor site. Assume that the removal process itself is not faulty, we are not randomly beaming away pieces of the vena cava, for example, but we might operate on cancerous tissue right next to it. The volume is equal to that of the replacement tissue, which depends on the size of the tumor or broken bone segment. The replacement tissue would have contained agents to improve healing, think nanobots and the like, but the air unfortunately does not.

What are the effects of such a mistake?  Where would the introduction of air (not oxygen, normal air) be benign/unnoticable, painful/dangerous or outright disastrous?
Edit: And how quickly would the effects become apparent, i.e. would the mistake be obvious to the operator?

Comment: Air is absorbed by your body fluids, unless it gets into your blood, because then you die from an embolism before that can happen.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but that would be a [pneumothorax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pneumothorax), wouldn't it?

Comment: The mistake would be instantaneously obvious to the operator. I presume that such an operation is performed under continuous endoscopy / RMN / X-ray control; a volume of air cannot be mistaken for a volume of normal tissue.

Comment: @AlexP Similar to the Therac-25 incidents, I am assuming that the process is mostly automated after the medical personnel in charge has determined the coordinates etc., the operator relies on error messages. Here, no error message (or a wrong one) would be displayed, hence the question whether/when the problem would be apparent from the patient's state rather than imaging tech.

Comment: Some surgeries involve pumping air into the abdomen so that things are easier to see and access.   Patients will generally have pains and cramps until this excess air is absorbed and dispersed.   As several answers mention, the air won't be the problem, but the missing pieces will be.

Answer (score 4):

**Probably death**

It depends if the air can escape the body. If it can't you'll probably get an air embolism.

The site will start to fill up with blood and other fluids. That much is clear. If the air can't escape the body, it'll probably get pushed into the veins towards the heart. From there some are likely to travel towards the brain, which can form a blockage. This will be akin to decompression sickness, but you can't reverse it. At the very least some part of the body will get the bubble blockade and die off.

I don't know how much air is needed to kill a person, but from what I can surmise from decompression sickness, it doesn't need to be much. The cancer in air volume is likely much higher, so probably a lot of the body will get affected by blockades. That something important will be blocked is likely as well, so my guess is that in practically all cases someone will die or receive severe permanent damage.

Comment: How rapidly would the blockade progress (seconds vs. minutes/hours)? Would it be obvious for the operator of the machine?

Comment: @Rika I was already speculating with known diseases, so unfortunately I don't have the answer. But further speculation is quickly, depending on the area.  The moment it gets into the veins, it'll move pretty quickly. I guess it would be seconds. Contrary to deepsea sickness, the bubbles don't have to form. They are already there. Symptoms are headaches and visual disturbances manifest as well as skin discolourations, but it can cut off internal organs as well. If it gets to the brain, the affected area will have about as much time as a flat lining patient.

Comment: Why/how would the air be forced into in the veins, as opposed to sitting there and slowly diffusing as a small pneumothorax would?

Comment: I guess the answer depends on how much blood supply there is, doesn't it; if there's lots, there's risk of embolism; if there's little to none, it'd probably be fine?

Comment: @sabik I'm not so sure. The difference with a pneumothorax is that it'll most likely have blood flowing through it in copious amounts. Most bones have good blood flow and cancer reroutes blood vessels to grow better. If it just suddenly disappears, the blood will start coming in and something has to push out. It's unlikely all air will stay in the pocket even if it's expanding. That is why I think in nearly all cases it'll be bad news.

Comment: Right. I guess that also provides an out, if the story demands survival — the tumor had been embolized prior to the procedure?

Answer (score 3):

You are severing a piece of tissue without any further action.

That will result into a bleeding from all the blood vessels which were not sutured; therefore, the air cavity will not contain air for long time. Depending on the actual location blood and something else will fill in the cavity.

If it is in the intestine for example, part of the gut content will go into it, which doesn't sound like a good situation.

If is part of a bone you have actually interrupted the bone continuity or strongly reduced it, again not a particularly good situation.

If the patient is lucky enough to not get a septic shock or an embolus because of the wreckage happened in their body, they might grow some filling of the cavity. There are cases of patients having survived a gun shot in their head and have lived ever after with a open hole in their forehead.

Comment: Is there a maximum volume that could be removed without such dire effects becoming obvious quickly (let's say while the patient is still in the treatment chamber)? Could you add details to what happens in the case of bones, do the tendons pulls the severed pieces together etc.?

Comment: I've searched multiple dictionaries, and I can't find any definition of `vases` that are related to biology.  What are `vases`?

Comment: @cowlinator, poor translation. I meant blood vessels

Answer (score 2):

**Air is ok.  Uncontrolled bleeding not ok.**

Think about an open surgery on that tissue next to the vena cava.  When they open the patient, there is air in the belly.  When they close the patient minus the tumor, some air is left behind.  It is resorbed.

Think about laparoscopic surgery.  They pump the belly full of gas like a balloon to lift the front of the abdominal wall like a tent and give them space to move around in.  Sometimes they use CO2 to fill the abdomen because it gets reabsorbed quicker because it is more soluble.

In either of these situations if the person has a scan shortly after surgery you can see bubbles still there.

The real issue with this transporter tech is bleeding.  If I have a tumor, that tumor is being fed by arteries.  If I beam the tumor out, somewhere there is an artery that now has a cut end.  Blood is going to come out!  Controlling bleeding is a major part of surgery.  Often they address blood vessels first, tying them off before cutting the far end.    For your fiction you can assert that the stuff you usually beam back in has factors to coagulate / cauterize or otherwise stop bleeding.  If you just have air, the blood that would have gone to the tumor will pour into that void and your patient may go into shock.

---

Additional reading

[Postoperative pneumoperitoneum on computed tomography: is the operation to blame?](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/25307607/)

> Abstract Background: Postoperative radiographs demonstrating
> pneumoperitoneum are a vexing problem for surgeons. This dilemma stems
> from uncertainty regarding the length of time for resolution of gas
> introduced operatively via either an open or a laparoscopic approach.
> We attempted to quantify the duration of pneumoperitoneum after both
> laparoscopic and open surgery in an animal model.
>
> Methods: A prospective study using 2 groups of 10 pigs (Sus scrofa)
> was performed. The animals were assigned to undergo either an
> exploratory laparoscopy or an open abdominal exploration.
> Postoperatively, sequential computed tomography (CT) scans were
> performed to assess for the presence of pneumoperitoneum.
>
> Results: Pneumoperitoneum resolution occurred sooner than average on
> CT scan in the laparoscopic group when compared to open group (1.79
> days vs 4.73 days respectively; P value of .02).

Comment: Best answer. I would add, air is usually ok in a broken bone situation (since the blood vessels around the wound are already open) but replacing part of a major artery...orthe blood inside a major artery with air... is gonna be bad.

Comment: @Willk Because the other answers indicate that the air itself would be the problem, I'd like to pose to you the what-if scenario of the process not being instantaneous, but rather like 3D printing: coagulate/tie-off, remove a slice of tissue, replace, etc., "slice by slice". Not to invalidate your answer, of course. With the bleeding problem out of the picture (mostly), what about the air *then*? If I've read your answer correctly, it would be mostly harmless, if inconvenient, unless mechanical forces from tendons or the general lack of tissue in that area cause further damage ( = bleeding).

Comment: @Rika.  Air is fine.  I added link and abstract - these experimental pigs kept air in their bellies for days after operations.  People too.    If there is a process for controlling bleeding that is something separate, having air is not a problem.  Imagine someone with a big tumor.  You do not replace it with some big tumor sized nontumor thing!  The guts and innards fall back together and fill the space.  Or if not the space fills with fluids from the body and eventually scars down.